# Word 2010 ... keeping a string of text from splitting onto two lines

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I am writing a memo that will go out to all our customers in which we refer to a period of dates (from 06-10-2016 to 12-06-2016 inclusively).
Is there a way I can keep this date period from splitting on two lines?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it, just replace spaces and hyphens (-) to their non-breaking equivalent:

- press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> to insert a non-breaking space
- press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to insert a non-breaking hyphen

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I will try above and see how the document looks. We actually have a string of text: we will be closed from "date to date inclusively" that we would like to keep together on the same line. I suggested that the paragraph containing the information be indented (on the left and right). This would highlight the information and with the right indentation, the information (string of text) would stay on the same line.